# Relations between many category theory structures - introductory texts and maps

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory, enriched-category-theory

There are many kinds of category theory structures. What are some good texts and good ways to remember the relations between them? For example, can there be a web of embedding relations between these category theory structures? (where can I find those webs to read.) Like which ones contain the other ones as more general cases. (Intersections and unions between different category theory structures.)

- unitary braided fusion category = unitary premodular category
- unitary fusion category
- unitary symmetric fusion category
- unitary modular category
- monoidal category = tensor category
- spherical fusion category
- modular tensor category

Here are some facts I know of

1.

$$
\text{unitary braided fusion category = unitary premodular category} \supset
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\text{(1) unitary symmetric fusion category}\\
\text{(2) unitary modular category}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

2. The center construction of the spherical fusion category defines a modular tensor category.

Please feel free to make comments and give a list of advice.

Comment: [Related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/788318/104041)

Comment: thanks +1 this helps

Answer (score 2):

Let me try to sort this out here for you. I'll do a first pass without unitarity, and then a second pass with.

A guiding analogy is as follows:

- Sets $\iff$ Categores
- Monoids $\iff$ Monoidal categories
- Groups $\iff$ Rigid monoidal categories
- Finite groups $\iff$ Fusion categories
- Finite abelian groups $\iff$ Braided fusion categories
- "Non-degenerate" Finite abelian groups $\iff$ Modular tensor categores.

For example, this is very concrete when considering categories of graded vector spaces. The category of $G$-graded vector spaces is a monoidal/rigid/fusion/braided fusion as $G$ is a monoid/group/finite group/finite abelian group. Note that this will never be an MTC. For non-degeneracy, you have to do something extra like pass to the Drinfeld center.

As you go up this chan there is strictly more data/axiomic information to keep track of. Also make note of the fact that linearity is a huge point, and properly this diagram might be more precise if  I added "linear abelian" before the first three points. Note that this is what you are doing implicitly in your question - you say that a monoidal category and tensor category are the same thing, but this is only true if your monoidal category is abelian.

Now, we start with a fusion category. There are two directions one can go - adding a braidng, or adding a pivotal structure. A braidng gives isomorphisms $A\otimes B\to B\otimes A$, and a pivotal structure gives you a natural isomorphism $A\to A^{**}$, giving you compatible left and right duals. Below I added to relevant relationships, where arrows denote forgetful functors and hooks denote that there is no structure being lost. That is, going from one to the other is a property not a structure.

[image]

We now consider unitarity. While this is a priori a structure (put inner products compatibly on all of your hom spaces), it is unique when it exists (reference: Reutter's [Uniqueness of Unitary Structure for Unitarizable Fusion Categories](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00220-022-04425-7)). Hence, it is really more of a property.

Unitary fusion categories are nice because they canonically allow one to define a very good spherical structure. They are no help in defining a braiding, however. What we do have is that any braiding on a unitary fusion category will be compatible (ref: [Galindo's On Braided and Ribbon Unitary Fusion Categories](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-mathematical-bulletin/article/on-braided-and-ribbon-unitary-fusion-categories/C318432A503EC38BE4F153A9E7912432)) and will give a ribbon unitary fusion category. There is still extra work that needs to be done to see if this category is non-degenerate. If it is non-degenerate, then you have yourself a unitary modular tensor category!

As for references, some can be found in Selinger's [survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.3347). However, this does not discuss unitarity or MTCs. I am currently working on a manuscript which includes a detailed discussion of these subtleties. You can find a working version on my [GitHub](https://github.com/Milo-Moses/Toric-Code-Introduction).